# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, netbeans

Hi im new here and to java so I am sure this will be a simple thing I overlooked, thanks for any help the code to my main class is here and the error code s at the bottom

```
package GameScreen;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class GameScreen extends JFrame
implements Runnable, KeyListener
{
private Thread animation = new Thread(this);
private Container back = getContentPane();
private AniScreen aniscreen = new AniScreen();

public GameScreen()
{
   super("moving image");
   setBounds(20,20,1024,768);
   back.add (aniscreen, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   animation.start();
   addKeyListener(this);

   setVisible (true);

}
   /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      GameScreen gameScreen = new GameScreen();
   }

   @Override
   public void run()
   {
      while (true)
      {
         aniscreen.repaint();
         try
         {
            Thread.sleep(30);
         }
         catch(InterruptedException ex)
            {

            }
      }

   }

   @Override
   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
   {
         }

   @Override
   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
   {
      if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
      {
        aniscreen.moveplayer(0,50);
      }
       if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP)
      {
        aniscreen.moveplayer(0,-50);

      }

   }

   @Override
   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
   {
      aniscreen.moveplayer(0,0);
   }
}
```

This is the error code:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:205)
    at GameScreen.AniScreen.<init>(AniScreen.java:15)
    at GameScreen.GameScreen.<init>(GameScreen.java:15)
    at GameScreen.GameScreen.main(GameScreen.java:33)
Java Result: 1
```

This is the aniscreen class

```
package GameScreen;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;


public class AniScreen extends JComponent
{
private int x = 0;
private int y = 0;
private int xMovement;
private int yMovement;

   private ImageIcon CINEMA = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource ("CINEMA.jpg"));
   private ImageIcon survivor = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("survivor.jpg"));
   @Override
   public void paint (Graphics g)
   {
      x = x + xMovement;
      y = y + yMovement;
      g.drawImage(CINEMA.getImage(),x,y,100,100,null);
      g.drawImage(survivor.getImage(),x,y,100,100,null); 
   }
public void moveplayer (int xmov, int ymov)
{
   xMovement = xmov;
   yMovement = ymov;
}

}
```

Comment: Have you debugged through to see what is null?

Comment: The AniScreen constructor is failing.  Where is that code?

Comment: The issue is in `AniScreen`, which you haven't shown.

Comment: Something is wrong with AniScreen constructor. I suspect you didn't pass a correct url to ImageIcon constructor.

Comment: I got it now it was the cinema image which I didn't need anymore so I just removed it. Thanks for the fast help :)

Comment: @Jayyf9 Add what you did as an answer and accept it to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is (most likely) occurring either here:

```
   private ImageIcon CINEMA = 
       new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource ("CINEMA.jpg"));
```

or here:

```
   private ImageIcon survivor = 
       new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("survivor.jpg"));
```

You are calling the `ImageIcon` constructor with a `null` reference.  That is happening because `getResource` is failing to find the resource that you have named.  When that happens, it returns `null` instead of throwing an exception.  The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) explains this.